# How to initialize socket with a secure connection?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, fastify

Currently, I have the following:

```
// client
. . .
import { io } from 'socket.io-client';
. . .
const socket = io('https://my_domain.com', {
        reconnectionDelay: 1000,
        reconnection: true,
        reconnectionAttemps: 10,
        transports: ['websocket', 'polling', 'flashsocket'],
        agent: false,
        upgrade: true,
        secure: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'development',
        rejectUnauthorized: false,
        query: { userId: user.id },
});
```

```
// server
. . .
import fastifySocketIo from 'fastify-socket.io';
. . .
app.register(fastifySocketIo, {
    pingInterval: 10000,
    pingTimeout: 5000,
    cookie: false,
});
. . .
```

Locally everything works just fine, but when `NODE_ENV` is set to production, a connection can't be made.

What am I doing wrong here? I'd like the socket to be over a secure connection when in production. My domain is mapped to a server that is hosted in the cloud, set up with Nginx and a certificate created by Let's Encrypt.